# How to rename a column header with a specific string from that header

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

My company uses a spreadsheet to record manufacturing data, but they also use the spreadsheet to give the user instructions.  Those instructions are in the column header for the data they need to record. I am trying to create a report from this spreadsheet for the Quality Engineer and I need to be able to pull a specific string from the column to use as a column name. Luckily, the string that I need is within parentheses and by demoting the headers and transposing, I was able to add a new column and extract text between delimiters. But, at this point, I do not know how to replace the original column names with the extracted one.

[image: Sample spreadsheet and desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to transpose etc.

You can just make a list of the new column names and do a rename.

The below code assumes

- The columns that need to be renamed will be renamed with the portion of the header in parentheses
- The parenthesized string will never be at the beginning of the existing column name
- There will only be a single parenthesized string

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Shop Order", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type text}, 
        {"Day", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Shift", Int64.Type}, 
        {"SCAN: New Antioxidant:#(lf)(P/N A14656-1)#(lf) Lot Number", type text}, 
        {"Scan: #(lf)Resin (PN A14658-1#(lf))Lot Number", type text}}),

//rename columns
    origColNames=Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),

//List.Transform modifies only those column names that have the parenthesized substring
    newColNames = List.Transform(origColNames, each let x=Text.SplitAny(_,"()") in if List.Count(x)=1 then x{0} else x{1}),

    renamedHdrs = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type", List.Zip({origColNames,newColNames}))

in
    renamedHdrs
```

[image]

***Edit with new column header data***

- You have added some problematic columns to your example.
- It seems the column headers that you do **not** want modified have parenthesized data at the end of the string.
- If that is always the case, you can handle that in code by changing the `newColNames` line:

```
    newColNames = List.Transform(origColNames, each 
        let x=Text.SplitAny(_,"()") 
        in 
            if List.Last(x) = "" or List.Count(x) = 1 
            then _ 
            else x{1}),
```

***Algorithm***

- Split the header on the parentheses
- Check the last element of the split

  - If the last element is a null string (`""`) or if there is only one element, then return the original header; otherwise return the 2nd element.

[image]

Comment: Ron, the above code looks like it worked, except opposite of what was expected.  It removed what was in parenthesis and left everything else.  I wanted to keep what was in parenthesis and discard the rest.  Thanks.

Comment: I apologize.  I was looking at the wrong worksheet.  On the worksheet where I applied the code above, I got an error message.  Apparently, they are using parenthesis to describe the measurement type, "(lbs)", in multiple columns.  This is creating duplicate column headers labeled "lbs".  At least, that is what I am assuming the error message is stating:

Comment: Error Message: Expression.Error: The field 'lbs' already exists in the record.
Details:
    Name=lbs
    Value=

Comment: @DavidLopez As you can see, the posted code works on your given data. Please post examples of the problematic column headers **and** your desired results after renaming. Might be best to do this by editing your question and then leave me a comment so I know when you've done it.

Comment: There are 120 columns in this spreadsheet and I missed the columns that also use parentheses, but not around the data I want to keep.  This spreadsheet format has been used for years and I was hoping to do all the data cleanup in Power Query.  I tried to do some cleanup by changing the parentheses to brackets but was not successful where text case was involved.  I was trying to use the Replace Values in one step by modifying the M code, but I couldn't get it to ignore capitals.  I guess I will have to use multiple steps to clean up the data and then use your code.

Comment: @DavidLopez Or you could post the problematic entries, and some method to differentiate those that are in parentheses that you want to keep, from those that you do not.  If you can do that, it shouldn't be too difficult to code.

Comment: @DavidLopez OK I have edited my answer with a change you can make that will account for the extra columns you have added to your example.  It appears that you do NOT want a modification if the the parenthesized item is at the very end of the column header.

Comment: Another great idea and, again, another failure.  The person that put this spreadsheet together was not very consistent.  They have other words in parentheses within the column header.  Can we take a different approach? The words in parentheses that I do not need is a short list.  Is it possible to remove the parentheses from a list of values? Either remove the parentheses or change them to brackets or something that will allow your original code to work.

Comment: @DavidLopez Should be possible. Why don't you give it a try and post a new question if you run into trouble. Include the problematic column headers and a list of words not needed. I'm thinking the issue could be handled by modifying the `newColumnNames` line to just ignore those items.